# Values to straighten wave texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, vector-mapping, vector

I am using the wave texture and am faced with a dilemma: by default, it is rotated in some obscure way. I want the bands of the texture to be aligned with each axis (x, y z) but cannot for the life of me figure out the rotation values required to do so. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably just easier to recreate it using math nodes rather than trying to align it to axis.

Use a *Math Node* set to *Cosine*; as input use your desired texture coordinates like *Object* or *Generated*.

Add a *Separate XYZ* node and use the desired axis as direction, then multiply it by any value to control density of the waves.

[image]

You can still run the output through a color ramp node to control progression and color, and covert the whole thing into a node group for simplicity sake, to make it visually cleaner, easier to reuse or port to other files.

Comment: Thanks so much. I also did some playing around, and found that adding an "Absolute" function to the end of the equation very closely mimics the wave texture. 10/10 answer though.