# Making a wave texture orientate properly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I made this part of the model:

[image]

What I need is to smooth the edge of the two materials. Similar to this question: [How can you smooth the edge between two materials?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/how-can-you-smooth-the-edge-between-two-materials)

But the problem is that the waves orientate at the wrong direction and there should be only one wave. That means the edge (blue line) between the two materials shouldn't be like this:

[image]

The edge should be basically a circle, like this:

[image]

And this is my current node setup:

[image]

So how could I change the orientation of the wave and make the edge go for a 360°?

[image]

Comment: Please upload your .blend with at least the faulty part + the material to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and link it to your question by editing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Values to straighten wave texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128871/values-to-straighten-wave-texture)

Comment: @WhatAMesh I upladed my .blend file

Answer (score 3):

You need to control the texture coordinates (and you need to add a gradient texture as well).

Let's break it down.

You are not using any coordinates to map the texture. By default Blender will use Generated coordinates to map procedural texutes. Generated coordinates will put the center of the texture in the lower left corner of the bounding box for the object.

[image]

Use object coordinates, they start at the origin of the object.

[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Npl.png)

To learn more about texture coordinates watch Bartek Skorupa's video: [Manipulate Texture Coordinates like a Boss](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)

Comment: It's really close to my problem, but not 100% (I think). What you can see on the images, is a part of a mesh. Of course, I tested your answer by separating the selected faces and changing the origin point, but still couldn't get it right. I'm having hard time explaining this (Engrish is difficult), so I added .blend file, so you can see what I'm talking about.